# Solution for a bpmn diagram with multiple, related inclusive gateways

Tags: bpmn

I've designed a complicated bpmn solution and am having trouble finding information that explains the behavior that's occurring. I could derive the behavior from testing but that could take a long time, as the tool I'm using is quite cumbersome.

Here's a picture of the diagram, in hopes that someone will be able to explain the behavior that's occurring.

[image]

What's happening is this:

1. 'Approval Process' splits into four branches, the bottom branch being based on a conditional.
2. The top two branches converge on an inclusive gateway
3. The third branch converges on a different inclusive gateway
4. The fourth branch converges on both the original inclusive gateway, as well as the later inclusive gateway

I've included a few notes on the diagram to explain where it is failing. The task near the top right is never hit, and I believe consequently the final process isn't hit either. Anyone know where it's going wrong?

Comment: I don't know what kind of cumbersome `bpmn` workflow execution engine you (have to) use, but all serious expert systems can explain their reasoning by providing some sort of "debug log" detailing on why was a choice selected or throw away. If you can not "debug" it interactively then I would search for such "verbose" debug log switch and then try to analyze the log. Without more details and some kind of ability to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the problem I have no idea. Does the "new material" conditional branch ever fire?

Comment: Yes the 'new material' process fires if the appropriate condition triggers it. I suspect that the issue has something to do with the parallel gateway after setup new material converging on two different inclusive gateways. I may just have to spend a few hours experimenting with different gateway variations until I can get it working. The only issue there is that I need to run the entire workflow to see if my change was correct.

Comment: I'm not `bpmn` expert (yet). I'm monitoring this Stack Overflow tag just to learn something. But quick look at [Camunda: BPMN Modeling Reference](http://camunda.org/bpmn/reference/#gateways-parallel-gateways) tells me that your drawing looks fine. It may be something not `bpmn`-related but something tool-related. For instance some tools may not like if branching starts with one gateway symbol and does not end with the same symbol. e.g. if you open flow with parallel gateway then there should be corresponding closing parallel gateway...

Comment: ... For instance in [UML Activity Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html) the `fork/join` and `decision/merge` nodes should be paired. Some tools trying to interpret the drawing may rely on it. Which tool do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the diagram above is defined how we wanted it to be. The issue turned out to be that the task which 'wasn't firing' was actually not given visibility for the type of user that we were running the workflow as. Since we couldn't see the task, we couldn't complete it, and so the final gateway was not progressing because an active branch was yet to reach it.

Doh!